# Traverse the Table rows to get values of its two TD

Tags: jquery, html

I Have an html table

```
<table id="tblProduct" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <form action="" method="post"> 
                <td><input type="hidden" class='hidenFeild' name="id" value="<?php echo $product_ids; ?>" /></td>
                <td><?php echo $odr; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows_pro['product_title']; ?></td>
                <td><span class="fa fa-gbp"></span><?php echo $rows_pro['amount']; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="spinner<?php echo $rows_shopings['product_id']; ?>" class="spinnerExample"/></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_dlt">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash icon-white"></i> Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
```

I have number of products in the table, I have to get the values of the first td and td that is having product quantity.

What i have tried up to now is:

```
$('#tblProduct > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

    $('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

    $('input[type="text"][name="quantity"]').each(function(){
        alert($(this).val());                                       
    });

});
```

But I am not getting the desired result. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: what are you expecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were couple of things which were missing in your code, I have modified your code to traverse through the table and list all the product details.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
  $('#tblProduct > tbody tr').not(':last').each(function(index) {
     var value = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();
     var qty =   $(this).find('input[type="text"][name="quantity"]').val(); 
     console.log("Value:"+ value +", Quantity:"+ qty);
  });
```

*Note:The above script will ignore the last row*

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/ra7gkycp/2/)

Comment: I have to discard last row, Coz i have submit button in it , is that possible

Comment: `tbody` should be `thead`?

Comment: @joy: check the updated code. @Adrian: `thead` is meant for table header, were as `tbody` is meant for body of the table structure.

Comment: kooooooooooooooooooool